# How to navigate to a new screen in react native using react navigation and the components are in a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am planning to use React Navigation in my project to navigate within two screens.

The index.js looks like

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

home.js contains a component called home and detailsScreen.js contains another component called detailsScreen.

1. What should I do to navigate to detailsScreen from Home? Do I have to import/export anything? If yes, where? The official docs (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/) only consider the scenario where all components are in the same file.
2. Can I call navigation.navigate in the following way?

```
return (
  <View>
    {navigation.navigate('Details')}
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate the any screen by `navigate` method. Just make sure that the screen is added in your stack.
For navigation, just follow
`navigation.navigate('Details')`

For accessing `navigation` in your component.You can pass the prop
function YourComponent({ navigation }){

```
//use navigation
//navigation.navigate("Details")
}
```

Please follow [Doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating)

Comment: Do I have to import anything in detailsScreen.js to use `navigation.navigate('Details')`?

Comment: Updated the comment. It may help.